# Movie with a boy that gets bigger while riding a flying ship in space

Tags: story-identification, movie

There's this movie I really liked that I watched a few years ago but I cannot figure out the name of it.

In the movie, this boy is imprisoned in a mine and forced to look for a specific science-fiction ore. The boy finds the ore but a random man steals it from him and claims that he found it instead. He says that he found it and tries to grab it. And somehow, he either falls off or has to walk off a ledge of some kind. But before hitting the bottom, he stops in mid-air and flies. Also in this movie, they ride a flying ship and momentarily are in space. When they're in space, the boy gets bigger and I think the others move slower.

Also, I think this movie had something to do with Peter Pan.

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[Pan](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3332064/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (2015)...?

It's evidently an *origin story* for Peter Pan.

> Twelve-year-old orphan Peter is spirited away to the magical world of Neverland, where he finds both fun and danger, and ultimately discovers his destiny: to become the hero who will be forever known as Peter Pan.

A tearful woman leaves her newborn son, Peter, on the steps on a London orphanage.

Twelve years later, during World War II, Peter and several other boys are kidnapped from the orphanage by pirates and taken aboard a flying pirate ship. Shortly afterwards, the ship ascends through the clouds into space. Having already tied a rope around his ankle to secure himself to the ship, Peter floats off towards Saturn and is shown to be even larger than it is for reasons that aren't explained; in fact, he effortlessly moves the planet with one hand, as if it were a helium-filled balloon. He then gets yanked back to the ship and is his normal size again.

> [image: Image of Peter floating towards Saturn, from "Pan" (2015).]
>
> <sub>*Pan* (2015)</sub>

The ship subsequently arrives in Neverland, where the boys are forced to mine for crystallised pixie dust. Peter finds a chunk of the stuff lodged in a cave wall, but a much older miner quickly snatches it from him and takes credit for having found it.

> [image: Image of a man snatching a chunk of crystallised pixie dust from Peter, from "Pan" (2015).]
>
> <sub>*Pan* (2015)</sub>

Peter is then accused of being a thief and made to walk the plank from the ship over a rocky chasm, but saves himself by briefly hovering in mid-air shortly before he hits the ground.

> [image: Image of Peter being made to walk the plank, from "Pan" (2015).]
>
> <sub>*Pan* (2015)</sub>